# Context menu keeps freezing on my screen

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

For those of you who don't know, this is a context menu:

[image]

My computer repeatedly freezes the option I clicked (not the whole menu) whenever I chose anything from any of the programs. The function it's supposed to run does run, but the menu is there until I restart my computer. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype caused that issue on my PC, I uninstalled it and it's fine now.